# Generic enum using case class in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have created the following enum objects

```
sealed trait MsgMapping[T] {def mycode: T;}

object Type1 {

  sealed trait msg[Int] extends MsgMapping[Int]

  case object A extends msg[Int]{val myCode = 0;}
  case object B extends msg[Int]{val myCode = 1;}

}

 object Type2 {

  sealed trait msgtype[String] extends MsgMapping[String]

  case object C extends msgtype[String]{val myCode = "xyz";}
  case object D extends msgtype[String]{val myCode = "def";}
 }
```

I want to  create a generic case class that can except any type of MessageMapping ,it can be an Integer/String or any data type

But this line gives error as it expects the type.

```
           case class EumType(valueType: MsgMapping [T])
```

The below works

```
 case class EumType1(valueType: MsgMapping [Int])
 case class EumType2(valueType: MsgMapping [String])
 case class TestEnum(value:EumType1)
 case class Test(val:TestEnum)
```

But I do not want to create EumType1 and EumType2 .Can anyone help to me to create a generic code for this

Update

As per suggestion

```
 case class EnumType[T](valueType: MsgMapping[T])

 case class TestEnum(value:EnumType[T]) 

 It will throw compile error since it expects type 
 here but i want to pass the type on this line   
 case class Test(val:TestEnum) ,whether it is Type1 /Type2
```

Comment: What if you just add the type parameter, `case class EnumType[T](valueType: MessageMapping[T])` ?

Comment: @slouc updated but have a doubt about calling EnumType

Comment: See https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Comment: @cchantep.nice link .Any suggestion if I want to do it without enumeratum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an existential type:

```
case class EumType(valueType: MessageMapping [_])
```

Comment: sry for deselecting the answer...went through https://gist.github.com/razie/595556 .Do not abuse _.Any advise on this

Comment: The advice is to "Avoid using many of them on the same line or small scope." I don't see this as conflicting with that... that said, I don't really agree with all of the advice on that page.